# Is there an R routine to plot a raster map of Bathymetry selecting only bathymetry value from 0 to -3000 excluding the values above zero?

Tags: r

I have a raster of the Gulf of Naples featuring bathymetry (i.e. negative values) values for oceanic expanses and altitude data for the landmass (i.e. positive values). I want to exclude from the map the positive values of bathymetry above the zero (the altitude), how can i do it?

Comment: Are you saying you have  a rater picture of a map with different colours and you want to exclude pixels with certain colours?

Comment: yes, it could be a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example

```
library(anglr)
library(raster)
geb <- anglr::gebco
plot(geb)
```

Solution

```
x <- reclassify(geb, cbind(0, Inf, NA))
plot(x)
```